# Java: Iterating a BiMap - Causing Me Some Issues

Tags: java, exception, hashmap, guava, minecraft

## Java Programming

### Issues With Iterating My Map

```
Iterator<Player> iterator = plugin.inreview.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Player key = (Player) iterator.next();
    chat.getRecipients().remove(key);
}
```

This throws:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException 
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? When this occurs, there is one key (with one value) in the map.

Also, it used to work until recently and I have done so much work on my Java file that I have no way to find out what made this occur. I can't do any while loop when iterating this map which complicates things a ton!

Notes:

- `Chat.getRecipients()` is not the same as `plugin.inreview`
- Used to work just fine
- It is a `HashBiMap`

Please, give me any hints and ideas that you may have.

Extra Details:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractBiMap$EntrySet$1.next(AbstractBiMap.java:314)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractBiMap$EntrySet$1.next(AbstractBiMap.java:306)
    at me.geekplaya.Judge.JudgeQuit.onPlayerQuit(JudgeQuit.java:25)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$2.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:251)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:58)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:339)
    at net.minecraft.server.ServerConfigurationManager.disconnect(ServerConfigurationManager.java:159)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:650)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkManager.b(NetworkManager.java:231)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:92)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkListenThread.a(SourceFile:108)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.h(MinecraftServer.java:471)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:374)
    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:417)
```

Comment: is this in a multithreaded environment? and what line in the snippet throws this (the `next` call or the `remove` call)?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Updated thread.

Comment: The code you posted shows you using the map's `keySet().iterator()`. However, the exception you posted shows the map's `entrySet().iterator()` being called. Are you sure the code you posted is really where the exception is occuring?

Comment: If you can post a small *complete* program that exhibits the failure, we'll surely be able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `remove` call is, as you say, not operating on the iterated sequence then there must be another thread updating `plugin.inreview`.

Check all write accessors of `plugin.review` and make sure no concurrent update is possible while a thread is reading using this code.

Note that such a bug could fail to manifest for a long time and then suddenly become a serious issue due to changes elsewhere that affect thread timings.

Comment: Will look into that now. You are saying that if there is something writing to it as it reads it, that could cause this?

Comment: Can't find anything that is writing to it / removing from it as it is being read.

Comment: Strange.  Are you sure there's no other event running in parallel?  Maybe add some diagnostics (including threadid) to your event handlers to observe sequencing and concurrency of callbacks - even if adding trace makes this stop, the output could demonstrate unexpected behaviour that you need to handle.  You could also add a size() call there on every loop, and see if it ever changes inside that loop.

Comment: It appears that: `.getValue()` does not work while `.getKey()` does. Therefore, I simply recreated another iterator, but inverted it, and used `.getKey()` :-/

Comment: Sounds like a feature of your container then.  Glad you resolved this.